# 2015 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Anime & Manga's [first moderator election](https://anime.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 3 new moderators are:

[image: ʞɹɐzǝɹ] [image: Toshinou Kyouko] [image: Madara Uchiha]

They'll be installed (or re-installed as the case may be) as [moderators](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Now is also a good time to thank senshin, who helped guide the site after JNat was hired away. We are incredibly grateful for all of the *pro tem* moderators who did so much to help Anime become the site it is today.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://anime.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/6186483249577984/0).

Comment: Congrats to all 3!